# Show movie then fade out div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay, fade

I'm working on an custom map, I have the map from google and alert the style - it all works. But I would like to show a HTML5 movie in an overlapping `div` and then fade it out after it is finished. This is what I've got so far.

#### jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#soundlogo').delay(400).fadeOut(400);
</script>
```

#### CSS

```
#soundlogo {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    background-color:#FFF;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
}
```

#### Body

```
<div id="soundlogo">
    <video width="100%" autoplay>
        <source src="video/soundlogo-web.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

The problem is that the fade never occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your jQuery code with the `ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#soundlogo').delay(400).fadeOut(400);
});
```

Comment: yes i needed to rewrite some pieces of code, like in the css i had the display show none. It works great now! Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about this but maybe you cannot directly call `delay()` on something you just selected. If you still don't get it to work, try to have a look at the classic `setTimeout` which could be appropriate here: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).